# I am not able to display the state when I do onSubmit

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have the  component that it is rendered 4 times in parent component. I would like to change the state in parent component and show the array with all the values of the four inputs. Anyway in the parent component when I do onSubmit the state does not seem to be updated and the value is not displayed. I think I am passing some props in a wrong way. Could anyone explain me properly what I am doing wrong? thanks a lot

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import CurrencyInput from 'react-currency-input-field';

function Stake(props) {
    const [newStake, setStake] = useState(['']);

    const changeStake = (e) => {
        setStake(e.target.value)
    }
    return (
        <>
            <CurrencyInput
                onChange={changeStake}
                newStakeProp={newStake}
                style={{
                    marginLeft: "40px",
                    width: "50px"
                }}
                placeholder="Stake"
                decimalScale={2}
                prefix="£"
            />
            <button onSubmitProp={props.onSubmit}>yes</button>
            <button>no</button>
            {newStake}
        </>
    );
}

export default Stake;
```

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Stake from './stake';

class FetchRandomBet extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            loading: true,
            bet: null,
            value: this.props.value,
            allStakes: ['']
        };
    }

    async componentDidMount() {
        const url = "http://localhost:4000/";
        const response = await fetch(url);
        const data = await response.json();

        this.setState({
            loading: false,
            bet: data.bets,
        });
    }

    render() {
        const { valueProp: value } = this.props;
        const { newStakeProp: newStake } = this.props;
        const { bet, loading } = this.state;

        if (loading) {
            return <div>loading..</div>;
        }
        if (!bet) {
            return <div>did not get data</div>;
        }
        return (
            < div >
                {
                    loading || !bet ? (
                        <div>loading..</div>
                    ) : value === 0 ? (
                        <div className="bet-list">
                            <ol>
                                <p>NAME</p>
                                {
                                    bet.map(post => (
                                        <li key={post.id}>
                                            {post.name}
                                        </li>
                                    ))
                                }
                            </ol>
                            <ul>
                                <p>ODDS</p>
                                {
                                    bet.map(post => (
                                        <li key={post.id}>
                                            {post.odds[4].oddsDecimal}
                                            <div className="stake-margin">
                                                <Stake
                                                    allStakes={this.state.allStakes}
                                                    onSubmit={() => { this.setState({ allStakes: [...newStake] }) }}
                                                >
{this.state.allStakes}
                                                </Stake>
                                            </div>
                                        </li>
                                    ))
                                }
                            </ul>
                        </div>
```

Comment: change `const [newStake, setStake] = useState(['']);` to this `const [newStake, setStake] = useState([]);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`newStake` is the state of your Stake component. But the parent cannot know about it if you are not passing it up from the child component.

So the Stake child component should have its own submit function, which then calls the `onSubmit` of the parent with a parameter holding `newStake`

The inline onSubmit in the parent should then accept the parameter holding newStake, of course

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import CurrencyInput from 'react-currency-input-field';

function Stake(props) {
    const [newStake, setStake] = useState(['']);

    const changeStake = (e) => {
        setStake(e.target.value)
    }

    const mySubmit = () => {
        props.onSubmit(newStake);
    }
    return (
        <>
            <CurrencyInput
                onChange={changeStake}
                style={{
                    marginLeft: "40px",
                    width: "50px"
                }}
                placeholder="Stake"
                decimalScale={2}
                prefix="£"
            />
            <button onSubmitProp={mySubmit}>yes</button>
            <button>no</button>
            {newStake}
        </>
    );
}

export default Stake;
```

Comment: I implemented this but it is not working:         <>
            <CurrencyInput
                onChange={changeStake}
                newStakeProp={newStake}
                style={{
                    marginLeft: "40px",
                    width: "50px"
                }}
                placeholder="Stake"
                decimalScale={2}
                prefix="£"
            />
            <button onSubmit={props.onSubmit}>yes</button>
            <button>no</button>
            {newStake}
        </>

Comment: how can I pass the parameter newStake? thanks again

Comment: I did <button onSubmitProp={mySubmit}>yes</button> and in the                                                 <Stake onSubmit={(newStake) => { this.setState({ allStakes:[...newStake]}}/>. On top of this parent component I have {this.state.allStakes} that is never shown. Also thanks for that your code cleared my console. Could you explain me why it is not showing the data?Thanks again

Comment: You placed `{this.state.allStakes}` inside the Stake component. You should move it to somewhere outside

Comment: I did this but still not working:  <div className="stake-margin">
                                                <Stake
                                                    onSubmit={(newStake) => { this.setState({ allStakes: [...newStake, newStake] }) }}/>
                                            </div>
                                            <div>{this.state.allStakes}</div>

Comment: Some questions: Is the value of the CurrencyInput an array? Why do you initiate the allStakes and newStake arrays with an empty string element? Are you sure that newStake is an array?

Comment: I've tried to do those changes in currencyinput in order to understand what you are explaining to me.Thanks a lot you're great

Comment: Actually getting this:Warning: Unknown event handler property `onSubmitProp`. It will be ignored.
    at button

Answer (score 0):

I tried to change onSubmit with onClick and it suddenly worked properly. Thanks for the help guys

```
<Stake
onClick={(newStake) => { this.setState({ allStakes: [...newStake, newStake] }) }}
 />
```

```
<button onClick={mySubmit}>yes</button>
```